# depends on message does not work for my node

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, msg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have some nodes that uses custom messages that I have in my workspace. In the package.xml I have declared it as depends (build and run), but if I clean the workspace when I use catkin_make to build everything it crash.

The crash is because the compiler try to build the node before generating the message and cannot find header files for the messages.

I think that I forgot something, but I cannot find a solution in the web.

Thanks you very much.

PD: I am using hydro.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/169546/depends-on-message-does-not-work-for-my-node/) by [Jonathan Ruiz](https://answers.ros.org/users/4379/jonathan-ruiz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2014-05-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package.xml isn't really used much during the build, what you are looking for is to add dependencies in your CMakeLists.txt. For instance, if you have a target called foo, and a package named my_msgs, you would "add_dependencies":

```
add_executable(foo src/foo.cpp)
# other link, etc commands
add_dependencies(foo my_msgs_generate_messages_cpp)
```

This will then cause CMake to build your messages before your node.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2